# Can I reassign/overwrite a std::string?

Tags: c++, string

Can I do the following in C++?

```
std::string a = "";
a = "hello";
a += ", good sir";
//use a in the program
a = "";
a = "bye";
a += " to you";
//use it for something else
```

If this is not a legitimate operation, may I incur into memory issues down the line? This last point is important to me because I have some of those and I am trying to figure out where they come from.

Comment: That is OK, no need to worry.

Comment: Unless `use a in the program` involves storing values returned from `a.c_str ()`, or `a.data ()` functions, and using them at a later time - it should work fine.

Comment: Also, there's no need to set the string to `""` before storing something else in it. So `std::string a = "hello"; a += " good sir"; a = "bye"; a += " to you";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the same variable for multiple purposes one-by-one. But actually I won't recommend you, the program will be a bit messy if you use only a single variable for multiple usage.

The class `std::string` automatically allocates the required bytes memory to store the string literal and reallocates when the string is changed.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string a = "hello"; // global a, allocates the required memory

int main(void) {
    std::string a = "world"; // local a, allocates the required memory
    ::a = "hello changed";   // accessing global a (reallocates memory)

    std::cout << a << std::endl; // local a
}
```

Still, there's no problem to use it twice and more. But take care of your code and make sure it's properly cleared before second or the nth use.

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine, no worries

std::string allocates memory as it's needed